# Is there ever a time when an appendicitis is not an emergency? Could it explain chronic pain in lower abdomen/pelvis?

Tags: abdominal, appendectomy, appendicitis, appendix

Is there ever a time when an appendicitis is not an emergency? Whenever I think of an appendicitis, I always envision it potentially bursting, warranting a swift appendectomy. But is that always the case? Could an appendicitis develop gradually and be the explanation for chronic pressurized pain in the lower abdomen/pelvis?

Comment: Chronic appendicitis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chronic appendicitis is possible but rare ([PubMed Central](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4416293/)).

Crohn's disease and ovarian cyst are more common cause of the right lower abdominal pain.

Constipation and IBS are even more common.